# Displaylink lag - known problem with workaround to switch to Wayland?

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, radeon, displaylink

I'm trying to set up a two external monitor setup on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 64 bit. I'm plugging in the two monitors via an HDMI port (which has always worked) and a USB 3.0 to HDMI port (which is the part causing the issue). Plugging in the HDMI through the adapter introduces lag, [which appears to be a known issue](https://github.com/DisplayLink/evdi/issues/181), whose proposed solution appears to be to "switch to Wayland".

I tried to follow [these instructions for doing so](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-20-04-desktop), editing /etc/gdm3/custom.conf to uncomment the appropriate line and I tried rebooting after changing it to "WaylandEnable=false" as well as to "WaylandEnable=true". Either way there was no gear icon on the login screen. I realize that I seem to be using X11 instead of Xorg (don't really know anything about these two Windowing Systems), but [this is what came up when I searched "ubuntu change from x11 to wayland"](https://itsfoss.com/switch-xorg-wayland/), which isn't any more helpful; all documentation on X11 seems to be years out of date.

The driver I'm using for display link was downloaded from [here](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu), "DisplayLink USB Graphics Software for Ubuntu5.4.1-EXE.zip" (which, despite the EXE in the filename, contains a linux executable file).

Open to any other adjustments in configuration. Let me know if I need to provide any additional info.

Processor is AMD® Ryzen 5 3500u with radeon vega mobile gfx × 8

Graphics is AMD® Radeon(tm) vega 8 graphics

Windowing System is X11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two steps seem to have addressed the problem. One is

```
sudo apt install gnome-session-wayland
```

apparently I didn't have wayland installed to begin with.

The other is I needed to comment out the

```
# WaylandEnable=false
```

line in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf. In retrospect I see that this is documented in [the page I linked](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-20-04-desktop), but I contend the page could probably have been made a bit clearer (and I acknowledge that that probably isn't the responsibility of anyone reading this question and answer).

Once I carried out these two steps, I was able to reboot and, upon opening the password entry in my login screen, the gear icon was visible in the lower right corner of the screen to switch to Ubuntu with Wayland. This fix has eliminated the lag.